# Highlighting values of a line chart in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, graph

I'm trying to make a graph that highlights decreases and increases [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJmY.png) in google sheets. However, as you can see on the left of the graph some of the increases are being highlighted as decreases. I know it's because the values overlap but the values causing this problem are needed as the start of another decrease

The data used is filtered to remove duplicates. If I use the unfiltered data this problem doesn't appear but I would prefer the filtered data.

The formulas in each column are:

F- `=FILTER(A:A,len(A:A))`

G- `=FILTER(B:B,len(B:B))`

H- `=IF(OR($G2<$G3,$G2>$G1),$G2,"")`

I- `=IF(OR($G2>$G3,$G2<$G1),$G2,"")`

Is there any way of fixing this?